# Can I copy-paste a Service Reference in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have over 5 service references in Project A that I'd like to move to Project B, thing is, soulution is bound to TFS and creating service reference through VS wizard takes a LONG time.
Can I simply copy paste the service references localted in the Service Reference/ folder?

I'm using VS2012 btw

Comment: You can try, but you may run into issues.  Namespaces would be the first one that comes to mind.  How big are these services?  I can't imagine the wizard taking an unbearably long time, especially since it's really a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: you can copy-paste service references.